# Como puedo cargar un array de imagenes en react gatsby desde un archivo JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, component, graphql, gatsby

Buenas con todos una consulta, estoy trabajando con react gatsby y estoy creando páginas desde un archivo JSON, este es mi archivo:

```
    [
    {
        "slug": "camping",
        "img": "../assets/images/campingDetails.jpg",
        "nombre": "Camping",
        "descripcion": "Acampada, campismo,​ campamento o el anglicismo camping​ hacen referencia a la actividad humana que consiste en colocar una vivienda temporal, ya sea portátil o improvisada, en un lugar con el fin de habitarla. También se denomina así al lugar físico donde se realiza esta actividad.",
        "galeria" : [
                {"imageC": "../assets/images/campingDetails.jpg"} ,
                {"imageC": "../assets/images/camping1.jpg"}
        ]
    },

    {
        "slug": "pesca",
        "img": "../assets/images/FishingDetails.jpg",
        "nombre": "Pesca",
        "descripcion": "La pesca se define como aquella actividad que se realiza para extraer peces. Puede realizarse en aguas continentales o marítimas. Ancestralmente, la pesca ha consistido en una de las actividades económicas más tempranas de muchos pueblos del mundo.",
        "galeria" : [
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/FishingDetails.jpg"} ,
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/pesca1.jpg"}
    ]
        
    },

    {
        "slug": "andinismo",
        "img": "../assets/images/climbingDetails.jpg",
        "nombre": "Andinismo",
        "descripcion": "El montañismo nace en los Alpes al final del siglo XVIII. Su objetivo es conseguir llegar a la cima de una determinada montaña, como un reto a la naturaleza, que en ocasiones se llega a perder la vida..",
        "galeria" : [
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/climbingDetails.jpg"} ,
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/andinismo1.jpg"}
    ]
    },

    {
        "slug": "senderismo",
        "img": "../assets/images/senderismoDetails.jpg",
        "nombre": "Senderismo",
        "descripcion": "El senderismo es una actividad deportiva no competitiva que consiste en caminar siguiendo un itinerario determinado. Se acostumbra a realizar en senderos balizados y homologados por el organismo competente de cada país, pero también por sendas, caminos rurales y vías verdes sin homologar.",
        "galeria" : [
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/senderismoDetails.jpg"} ,
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/senderismo1.jpg"}
    ]
    },

    {
        "slug": "montaña",
        "img": "../assets/images/montanaDetails.jpg",
        "nombre": "Montaña",
        "descripcion": "El montañismo es el deporte de caminar y hacer excursiones por las montañas. A diferencia del senderismo, que se realiza normalmente por senderos señalizados, y el trekking, una travesía de varios de días por entornos lejanos, el montañismo tiene como motivación el destino, la montaña, y por rutas de más dificultad.",
        "galeria" : [
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/montanaDetails.jpg"} ,
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/montana1.jpg"}
    ]
    }

]
```

Estoy creando las paginas basado en el slug, es decir se crea la página y me carga la información de acuerdo al slug,es decir muestro el nombre y la descripción y la imagen de fondo, eso funciona correctamente. Lo que necesito y no encuentro solución es agregar las imágenes que se encuentran en galería en cada uno de los objetos. Alguna idea por favor? Llevo un tiempo en esto y no lo consigo.

Esta es mi consulta en graphql:

```
    query MyQuery { detallesCategoriasJson(slug: {eq: "camping"}) {
    nombre
    descripcion
    img {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
    galeria {
      imageC {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid {
                        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    } 
   } 
  }
```

y estos son los resultados que obtengo:

```
    {
"data": {
    "detallesCategoriasJson": {
      "nombre": "Camping",
      "descripcion": "Acampada, campismo,​ campamento o el anglicismo camping​ hacen referencia a la actividad humana que consiste en colocar una vivienda temporal, ya sea portátil o improvisada, en un lugar con el fin de habitarla. También se denomina así al lugar físico donde se realiza esta actividad.",
      "img": {
        "childImageSharp": {
          "fluid": {
            "base64": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
            "aspectRatio": 1.5037593984962405,
            "src": "/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/14b42/campingDetails.jpg",
            "srcSet": "/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/f836f/campingDetails.jpg 200w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/2244e/campingDetails.jpg 400w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/14b42/campingDetails.jpg 800w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/47498/campingDetails.jpg 1200w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/ec6c5/campingDetails.jpg 1280w",
            "sizes": "(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"
          }
        }
      },
      "galeria": [
        {
          "imageC": {
            "childImageSharp": {
              "fluid": {
                "base64": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
                "aspectRatio": 1.5037593984962405,
                "src": "/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/14b42/campingDetails.jpg",
                "srcSet": "/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/f836f/campingDetails.jpg 200w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/2244e/campingDetails.jpg 400w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/14b42/campingDetails.jpg 800w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/47498/campingDetails.jpg 1200w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/ec6c5/campingDetails.jpg 1280w",
                "sizes": "(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "imageC": {
            "childImageSharp": {
              "fluid": {
                "base64": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
                "aspectRatio": 0.6666666666666666,
                "src": "/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/14b42/camping1.jpg",
                "srcSet": "/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/f836f/camping1.jpg 200w,\n/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/2244e/camping1.jpg 400w,\n/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/14b42/camping1.jpg 800w,\n/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/47498/camping1.jpg 1200w,\n/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/ec6c5/camping1.jpg 1280w",
                "sizes": "(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },  
"extensions": {}  
}
```

Este es mi archivo componente.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Button from '../components/Button'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Image from 'gatsby-image';


export const query = graphql`
  query ($slug : String! ) {
    detallesCategoriasJson(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
      nombre
      descripcion
      img {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
      galeria {
        imageC {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;


const templateDetalleCat = ({data}) => {

    const tD = data.detallesCategoriasJson;

    return (
        <Layout>
          <TemplateContainer>
            <TemplateBg>
            <Image 
              fluid={tD.img.childImageSharp.fluid}
              alt={tD.nombre}
            /> 
            </TemplateBg>
                <TemplateContent>
                    <TemplateItems>
                      <TemplateH1> {tD.nombre} </TemplateH1>
                      <TemplateP>{tD.descripcion}</TemplateP>
                      <Button primary="true" big="true" round="true" to="/tienda">Shop now</Button>
                    </TemplateItems>
                </TemplateContent>
                
          </TemplateContainer>
          <CarContainer>

          </CarContainer>
        </Layout>  
    )
}

export default templateDetalleCat

const CarContainer = styled.div`
  background: black;
`

const TemplateContainer = styled.div`
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -80px;
  color: #fff;

  :before{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      background: linear-gradient(
          180deg, 
          rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, 
          rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%
        ),
        linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
  }
`
const TemplateBg = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
`
const ImageBg = styled.img`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
`
const TemplateContent = styled.div`
    z-index: 3;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 0rem calc((100vw - 1300px) /2);
`

const TemplateItems = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.1;
    
`
const TemplateH1 = styled.h1`
    font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 6vw, 4rem);
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
`
const TemplateP = styled.p`
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5vw, 1.5rem);
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
`
```

Entre las etiquetas CarContainer necesito mostrar las imagenes que se encuentran en galeria.

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar estaría muy agradecido.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor el problema? Hasta donde entiendo, obtienes las imágenes de la galería correctamente y lo que necesitas es alguna manera de mostrarlas dentro de cada página, ¿correcto?

Comment: En graphql si me obtiene la informacion que necesito, lo unico que puedo mostrar en la pagina es el nombre, descripcion y el img de fondo, quiero mostrar en un carrousel las imagenes de galeria pero no lo consigo